# TYPO3 modyfing img source on tt_news list item

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I'm trying to add additional parameter to tt_news img list source: `data-src="path-to-img"`. Is it possible? I try with generic marker but without any success:

```
plugin.tt_news.genericmarkers {
  data = imgsource
  imgsource = TEXT
  imgsource {
    field = image
    wrap = <img src="uploads/pics/|" data-src="uploads/pics/|" />
    file.maxW = 112
    file.maxH = 124
  }
}
```

But on output I only have this in source: `<img src="uploads/pics/img.jpg" data-src="uploads/pics/` without second img source, img size and close tag.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks before I show you an example:

- the »wrap« property only allows one pipe (TYPO3 is replacing the first »|« character with the current value), that why your second parameter is empty
- the TEXT objekt only allows value and all properties listed in the »stdWrap« section (see TEXT object: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Text/Index.html, list of all stdWrap-properties http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html)
- so TEXT does have properties like »wrap« or »case« or »substring«, but no »file«
- what you want is an IMAGE object, which allows to manipulate images

  ```
  plugin.tt_news.genericmarkers {
      imgsource = IMAGE
      imgsource {
          file.import = uploads/pics/
          file.import.field = image
          file.import.listNum = 0
          file.width = 250
          # if you just want to link the original image
          params.field = image
          params.wrap = data-src="/uploads/pics/|"
          /*
          # if you want want to manipulate the image as well, then use this code instead
          # IMG_RESOURCE is almost the same as IMAGE, but returns only the path to the resulting image, not the »<img src="">«-Markup
          params.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
          params.cObject {
              file.import = uploads/pics/
              file.import.field = image
              file.import.listNum = 0
              file.width = 500
              stdWrap.wrap = data-src="|"
          }
          */
      }
  }
  ```